# npm install angular project fails due to coffee-script@1.12.8 postinstall

Tags: angular, npm, coffeescript, installation, package.json

I have an issue trying to reinstall my node_modules (`npm i`) on my Angular project. I used to be on node v7 and npm v4, now updated to latest LTS but not solving anything.
It was working fine until around 12:00am GMT..

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --locale=fr && gulp postbuild --BUILD",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run test:once",
    "test:serve": "ng test",
    "test:once": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "test:headless": "ng test -c karma-ci.conf.js --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint --type-check",
    "validate": "npm run lint && ng test --watch=false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.6.4",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.6.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.3",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.17",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-maven-deploy": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  }
}
```

The stack trace is as below:

```
> coffee-script@1.12.8 postinstall C:\Users\merlosy\workspace\myapp\myapp-front\node_modules\coffee-script
> node --eval 'if (require("./package.json").name === "coffee-script") { var red, yellow, cyan, reset; red = yellow = cyan = reset = ""; if (!process.env.NODE_DISABLE_COLORS) { r
ed = "\x1b[31m"; yellow = "\x1b[33m"; cyan = "\x1b[36m"; reset = "\x1b[0m"; } console.warn(red + "CoffeeScript has moved!" + reset + " Please update references to " + yellow + "\
"coffee-script\"" + reset + " to use " + yellow + "\"coffeescript\"" + reset + " (no hyphen) instead."); console.warn("Also, a new major version has been released under the " + y
ellow + "coffeescript" + reset + " name on NPM. This new release targets modern JavaScript, with minimal breaking changes. Learn more at " + cyan + "http://coffeescript.org" + re
set + "."); console.warn(""); }'

[eval]:1
'if
^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:462:27)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:163:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm WARN ts-simple-ast@0.86.0 requires a peer of typescript@2.6.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! coffee-script@1.12.8 postinstall: `node --eval 'if (require("./package.json").name === "coffee-script") { var red, yellow, cyan, reset; red = yellow = cyan = reset = "";
 if (!process.env.NODE_DISABLE_COLORS) { red = "\x1b[31m"; yellow = "\x1b[33m"; cyan = "\x1b[36m"; reset = "\x1b[0m"; } console.warn(red + "CoffeeScript has moved!" + reset + " P
lease update references to " + yellow + "\"coffee-script\"" + reset + " to use " + yellow + "\"coffeescript\"" + reset + " (no hyphen) instead."); console.warn("Also, a new major
 version has been released under the " + yellow + "coffeescript" + reset + " name on NPM. This new release targets modern JavaScript, with minimal breaking changes. Learn more at
 " + cyan + "http://coffeescript.org" + reset + "."); console.warn(""); }'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the coffee-script@1.12.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Anyone can reproduce?
Any workaround, downgrading a lib?

Thanks

Comment: We have this issue also, still working on a solution will keep you informed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is broken by the 1.12.8 release of coffeescript, which was released early this morning.  There's an [issue open](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4805) for it with coffeescript and it looks like this has affected a lot of people.

You can work around it by referencing the previous version exactly in your devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "coffee-script": "1.12.7",
    ....
```

I'd recommend keeping an eye on the issue and removing your explicit dependency once this has been fixed.

**Update**: The problematic version has been removed, and this workaround should now be unnecessary and can be removed.

Comment: Working well! I hope this will get properly fixed ASAP